# *this-> can not be used as a function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

Here's an excerpt of a class which I have created inside a header file :

```
typedef double real;

class Grid{
   public :

      explicit Grid ();
      explicit Grid(size_t level );
      Grid(const Grid & grid );

      ~ Grid ();


      const Grid & operator =( const Grid & grid );

      inline real & operator ()( size_t i , size_t j );
      inline real operator ()( size_t i ,size_t j ) const;

      void fill( real value );
      void setBoundary ( real value );

 private :

   size_t y_ ; // number of rows 
   size_t x_ ; // number of columns 
   real h_ ; // mesh size 
   real * v_ ; //  values 
};
```

and here's an excerpt from the code I have written for the previously declared functions in a separate .cpp file. Note that I have only included parts which were relevant to my error.

```
  inline real&  Grid :: operator ()( size_t i , size_t j ){
    if( (i >= y_) || (j>=x_ ) )
      throw std::invalid_argument( "Index out of bounds" );
    return v_ [i* x_ +j];
  }

  inline real Grid::operator ()( size_t i ,size_t j ) const{
    if( (i >= y_) || (j>=x_ ) )
      throw std::invalid_argument( "Index out of bounds" );
    return v_[i* x_+j];
  }


  void Grid::fill( real value ){
   for(size_t i=1;i<y_;++i){
    for(size_t j=1;j<x_;++j)
     v_(i,j)=value;
   }

  }

 void Grid::setBoundary ( real value ){
    size_t i = 0;
    for(size_t j=0;j<x_;++j){
     v_(i,j)=value;
    }
    i = y_;
    for(size_t j=0;j<x_;++j){
     v_(i,j)=value;
    }
    size_t j = 0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<y_;++i){
     v_(i,j)=value;
    }
    j = x_;
    for(size_t i=0;i<y_;++i){
     v_(i,j)=value;
    }
  }
```

I am getting an error

> `((Grid*)this)->Grid::v_` cannot be used as a function

whenever I am trying to use the overloaded `()` operator, inside the `fill` and `setBoundary` function. I have tried looking for similar errors online, but unfortunately couldn't make much progress. Do you have any suggestions, because I think the implementation of the overloaded operator is correct and as far as I know I haven't named any function with the same name as a member variable.

Answer (score 3):

`v_` is a `real*`, i.e. a pointer. Pointers don't have an `operator()`, so you can't write `v_(something)`.

You've provided an overload of `operator()` for your `Grid` class. If you want to use that overload, you need to use `()` on an object of your `Grind` class. `v_` is not an object of your `Grid` class.

You probably want to invoke `operator()` on the current object (i.e. the object that `fill` or `setBoundary` are being called on). To do that, you'd write `(*this)(arguments)`.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `v_(i,j)`, you are not calling the overloaded `()` operator. You should try `(*this)(i,j)` instead.